# How can I see all the relations betwen tables in phpmyadimn

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, database-relations

I have a db that has around 280 tables, is there a way in phpmyadmin to see all the relations between all the tables? I need to export some data an I need to export 1st the tables that have no dependencies and after the ones that depend on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your `Phpmyadmin` Select database you can see `more` link in that window from the dropdown select `designer`

Comment: Thank you, I did that that but it'll return an error after a while, the URI is too long.